# Theano logistic regression understanding code

Tags: python, theano

I am used to C/Java like programming, and sometimes I am getting a headache on understanding the Python notation.

On the logistic regression code available online, I am trying to understand this line of code:

```
-T.mean(T.log(self.p_y_given_x)[T.arange(y.shape[0]), y])
```

It is basically saying perform this average:
$\begin{align}
J(\theta) = - \left[ \sum_{i=1}^{b} \sum_{k=1}^{K}  1\left\{y^{(i)} = k\right\} \log \frac{\exp(\theta^{(k)\top} x^{(i)})}{\sum_{j=1}^K \exp(\theta^{(j)\top} x^{(i)})}\right]
\end{align}$ where $b$ is the batch size.

So is it related to theano code, or it is just a python notation ?
I am interested exactly on this piece of code:

```
T.log(self.p_y_given_x)[T.arange(y.shape[0]), y]
```

If you could please give me some explanation.

Answer (score 3):

I agree the code may be hard to read at the first glance, but I find the [comment](http://deeplearning.net/tutorial/code/logistic_sgd.py) pretty clear:

- `y.shape[0]` is (symbolically) the number of rows in `y`, i.e., number of examples (call it `n`) in the minibatch
- `T.arange(y.shape[0])` is a symbolic vector which will contain `[0,1,2,... n-1]`.
- `T.log(self.p_y_given_x)` is a matrix of Log-Probabilities (call it `LP`) with one row per example and one column per class
- `LP[T.arange(y.shape[0]),y]` is a vector v containing `[LP[0,y[0]], LP[1,y[1]], LP[2,y[2]], ..., LP[n-1,y[n-1]]]`
- `T.mean(LP[T.arange(y.shape[0]),y])` is the mean (across minibatch examples) of the elements in v, i.e., the mean log-likelihood across the minibatch.

Everything is Python notation (but sometimes using Theano functions).

Comment: Thank you for you answer, in fact it is 2D-array indexing using Numpy, for more details have a look at the link bellow (section: Indexing Multi-dimensional arrays): http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/user/basics.indexing.html

Comment: I am struggling with the T.arange(y.shape[0]) part, as I understand this is a list of indices from 0 to n-1 (n being the number of examples in the mini batch), where is this used in the code and for what?